# Google Drive API thumbnailLink CORS

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, cors

I'm trying to render the `thumbnailLink` image returned from the Google Drive API's [/files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) endpoint. I'm doing this in an app running from localhost.

The docs mention this:

> If the file isn't shared publicly, the URL returned in Files.thumbnailLink must be fetched using a credentialed request.

How do I build this "credentialed request"? I tried:

1. Adding my OAuth access token as an `access_token` query parameter. This gives me a 403 response (same as without the `access_token` param).
2. `fetch()`ing the image as a blob with the header `{ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken }`. This request fails with a CORS error.

My OAuth access token has the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

---

EDIT: Minimal examples:

```
// This gives me a 403 response
function ThumbnailUsingUrl({ thumbnailLink }) {
  const thumbnailUrl = new URL(thumbnailLink);
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(thumbnailUrl.search);
  searchParams.set("access_token", "my_access_token");
  thumbnailUrl.search = searchParams.toString();

  return <img src={thumbnailUrl.toString()} />;
}

// This gives me a CORS error
function ThumbnailUsingBlob({ thumbnailLink }) {
  const [blob, setBlob] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(thumbnailLink, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer <my_access_token>`,
        },
      });

      setBlob(await response.blob());
    })();
  }, []);

  if (!blob) return null;

  return <img src={URL.createObjectURL(blob)} />;
}
```

Comment: Did you try 2nd step in server side instead of browser ?

Comment: @bogdanoff Hmm, I haven't. Is a server the only way to fetch the thumbnail? I'm trying to avoid having to spin up a server, mine's a purely client-side Electron app.

Comment: Could you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to check how the call is being made?

Comment: I think that if your thimnbnailLink is like `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/###=s220`, even when the access token is not used, the image can be retrieved. So, when you test your script with a URL like `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/###=s220` without the query parameter and the access token, what result will you obtain? I'm worried about the status code 403.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo Thanks for your response, I've added example code for both approaches.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your response, the thumbnail URLs are `https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/...` for uploaded files like PDFs, and `https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?...` for Google Docs, Slides, etc. I get a 403 for all of them with or without an `access_token` query param. I've updated my question with example code.